Multiplicación de matrices con MPI
Hola tengo que hacer una multiplicación de matrices en C usando MPI(message parsing interface), donde tengo que hacer A*B=C, donde con la matriz A tengo que hacer un broadcast y con B hacer un scatter para repartirla de manera local y crear una submatriz C_local donde guardará los resultados locales y luego hacer un gather para juntar los resultados en C. Bien el producto se tiene que hacer con cblas_dgem. El caso es que me da un error de segmentation fault y no entiendo porqué. El trabajo es a repartir entre 4 nodos.
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cblas.h>
#include <math.h> // Para fabs

// Función para generar matrices aleatorias
void generar_matriz(double* matriz, int filas, int columnas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < filas * columnas; i++) {
        matriz[i] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }
}

// Función secuencial para multiplicar matrices de forma clásica
void multiplicar_matrices_secuencial(double* A, double* B, double* C, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            C[i * n + j] = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                C[i * n + j] += A[i * n + k] * B[k * n + j];
            }
        }
    }
}

// Función para comparar dos matrices y verificar si son iguales
int comparar_matrices(double* C1, double* C2, int n) {
    double tolerancia = 1e-6; // Diferencia permitida por errores numéricos
    for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {
        if (fabs(C1[i] - C2[i]) > tolerancia) {
            return 0; // Las matrices no son iguales
        }
    }
    return 1; // Las matrices son iguales
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n = atoi(argv[1]); // Toma el tamaño n de la línea de comandos
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    double *A, *B, *B_local, *C_local, *C_paralelo, *C_secuencial;
    if (rank == 0) {
        // P0 genera las matrices A y B
        A = (double*)malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
        B = (double*)malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
        generar_matriz(A, n, n);
        generar_matriz(B, n, n);

        // Para almacenar el resultado final de la versión paralela
        C_paralelo = (double*)malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
        // Para almacenar el resultado secuencial
        C_secuencial = (double*)malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));

        // Multiplicación secuencial clásica para comparar
        multiplicar_matrices_secuencial(A, B, C_secuencial, n);
    }

    B_local = (double*)malloc(n * (n / 4) * sizeof(double));
    C_local = (double*)malloc(n * (n / 4) * sizeof(double));

    // Distribución de la matriz B en bloques y replicación de A
    MPI_Scatter(B, n * (n / 4), MPI_DOUBLE, B_local, n * (n / 4), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(A, n * n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Calculo local de C_local usando dgemm de BLAS
    cblas_dgemm(CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans,
                n, n / 4, n,
                1.0, A, n, B_local, n,
                0.0, C_local, n);

    // Reunión de los resultados
    MPI_Gather(C_local, n * (n / 4), MPI_DOUBLE, C_paralelo, n * (n / 4), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {
        // Comparar el resultado paralelo con el secuencial
        if (comparar_matrices(C_secuencial, C_paralelo, n)) {
            printf("Las matrices calculadas por la versión secuencial y paralela son iguales.\n");
        } else {
            printf("Las matrices calculadas por la versión secuencial y paralela son DIFERENTES.\n");
        }
    }

    // Liberar la memoria
    if (rank == 0) {
        free(A);
        free(B);
        free(C_paralelo);
        free(C_secuencial);
    }
    free(B_local);
    free(C_local);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

